# Error - [trust-cert] TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null

Tags: sharepoint, gulp, sharepoint-online, yo

I am Building my first SharePoint client-side web part. I have used `gulp trust-dev-cert` and the output is coming with 2 errors. How to fix it?

```
C:\sharepoint>gulp trust-dev-cert
Build target: DEBUG
[12:50:19] Using gulpfile C:\sharepoint\gulpfile.js
[12:50:19] Starting gulp
[12:50:19] Starting 'trust-dev-cert'...
[12:50:19] Starting subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig'...
[12:50:19] Finished subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig' after 5.6 ms
[12:50:19] Starting subtask 'trust-cert'...
[12:50:22] Error - [trust-cert] TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
[12:50:22] Error - 'trust-cert' sub task errored after 2.59 s
 Cannot read property 'toString' of null
[12:50:22] 'trust-dev-cert' errored after 2.93 s
[12:50:22]
[12:50:23] ==================[ Finished ]==================
Error - [trust-cert] TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
Error - 'trust-cert' sub task errored after 2.59 s
 Cannot read property 'toString' of null
[12:50:23] Project sharepoint version:0.0.1
[12:50:23] Build tools version:3.12.1
[12:50:23] Node version:v10.23.0
[12:50:23] Total duration:8.05 s
[12:50:23] Task errors:2
```

[This is the content in the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5rtu.png)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run gulp trust-dev-cert **in the specific SPFX Solution folder**, make sure the folder path "C:\sharepoint" is valid:

[image]

Comment: I have installed all in the sharepoint folder itself. That is the only solution folder I created. Should I run the gulp in the directory(it contains node_modules, src, config etc..) or any specific folder of the directory?

Comment: Which Node version you are using ? If it's Node.js v8, then it could be a bug:https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4987 Try to use Node.js v10.x instead

Comment: I am using Node.js v10.x.